# Knockout-style dynamic page with Razor viewmodels and @functions?

Tags: c#, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm building a page in which the user can query a set of data by building up a set of search criteria, something like the way the Visual Studio TFS plugin lets you search work items: a table of conditions, where you can keep adding rows. You select "and" or "or" for the join condition, then select a field, enter a value, and select whether you want things that do or do not match it:

```
1. show items where [Field] [is|is not] [value]
2.         [and|or] [Field] [is|is not] [value]
3.         [and|or] [Field] [is|is not] [value]
etc...
```

Now, I'm looking at ways to build this, and I had a thought. In the past, I've used Knockout, but this requires me to have models in Javascript to map the data to, which seems redundant when I already have those models in C# in the server-side code. Of course, I can use Razor code to foreach through a list of criteria that's part of the model in a strongly-typed view, but I can't find a tidy way to add to this list.

The model structure in C# is (roughly) like this:

- `Field`:

  - field name
  - list of options for the value
  - boolean value for the is/is not option.
- `Criterion`:

  - `Field`
  - selected value
  - combination type (and/or)
- `Query`:

  - list of `Criterion`s (that looks weird not saying Criteria)
  - start and end date
  - the user's access level
  - view field and sorting options
- `QueryViewModel`:

  - `Query`
  - assorted lists to populate the view options selection area
  - a little metadata for other (unrelated) displays on the page

In Knockout, I'd add an on-click method to the "add search criteria" button to add new entries to the list of criteria. Can I use a Razor functions block (`@functions { ... }`) to achieve a similar result? I've tried a few things, but I either find that the viewmodel doesn't seem to be in scope, or that there's no way to update the page to show the new contents of the viewmodel (although I'm experimenting with something that involves passing the newly-updated viewmodel to a partial view, which might work somehow). Can this be done, or do I need to take a deep breath and go back to the Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize/deserialize your C# objects as JSON, either with standard MVC controllers and JSONResult or with Web API in MVC 4.  This means you dont have to explicitly redefine your c# objects in javascript.

In the browser you can use the knockout mapping plugin to make your json properties into knockout observables if required.

This is generally a cleaner and more robust approach than dynamically loading and rendering html from the server (if thats what you were suggestiong - wasnt 100% clear from your post).